# Robust file transfer from mobile devices to server

Tags: java, php, android, iphone, ios

What I need is a solution(a library) for file transfer from mobile devices(iOS, Android) to sever(PHP). The basic requirement is that files should be split into chunks so that if data connection is lost in the middle of sending file, I don't need to re-send the whole file. Low memory usage is also obligatory.
I thought about something like p2p approach. Best practices?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done some r&d by yourself?

Comment: @13hsoj No r, I guess, just d. Now splitting file manually and sending chunks using multipart post. But implementations differ on iOS and Android, so looking for some complete solution.

Comment: why would p2p help? You still need to get it off of the device. That would be the major hurdle. So delete p2p out of your brain right now. Why can't you use a service like dropbox or drive?

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend you POST request. Look [here](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/) for usage, low memory usage, but you have to handle spliting file yourself (which is should be really simple, just modify that solution sending data to server by chunks saving your actual position).

Comment: That's what I have now. I was looking for more complete solution.

Comment: +1 this seems like the right solution. Just keep track of what you already sent. @mighter, If you don't want to hear answers you already have, maybe you should post your current code.

Comment: The link posted is as a complete solution as it gets :)

Comment: you should add though how in that solution handle a connection lost event ie. IOException.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using HTTP as underlying technique.

On Android I would recommend loopj's async http library ([loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)), as you get automatic retrying, cookie handling and some other nice features in clean and easy to use package. You might especially have a look at the chapter "Uploading Files with RequestParams".

For splitting the files have a look at this [snippet](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Splitfile.htm). In this case the files are directly written to the filesystem, using another output stream will allow you to easily store the chunks in memory or wherever you like. If memory usage is of great concern, you may try reading the chunk until the buffer is full and then directly sending it to your server, read the next chunk, send it, etc, etc.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is a gap in tools at the moment.. an open source drop box if you like.. I am building one now.. www.nofolder.com is who we are, it's almost at beta and will include an android app.. basically there AREN'T any good tools to do this.. the nearest best thing is sparkleshare  I know they have an android app

Comment: when/if you do get this in a beta and have an android app and you want feedback post it in reddit.com/r/androidapps. I'll keep an eye out and help if I can.

Comment: thanks.. can you email me conradbate _at_ hotmail _dotcom_